# class constructors in Xtend

Tags: java, eclipse, xtend

I'm trying out [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/xtend/). Is it possible to make constructors? It seems so simple, but I'm getting an error when I try something like this:

```
class Scope extends Rect {

    public Scope(){
        super()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try `def Scope() { }` ?

Comment: Ahaa! That works. Now how would I access the superclass constructor? `super` doesn't seem to work as it usually does. Still new to this.

Comment: Just a followup, see the comment below for an explanation. It didn't actually work. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Constructors are defined by overloading a new() method:

```
class MyClass extends AnotherClass {
  new(String s) {
    super(s)
  }

  new() {
    this("default")
  }
}
```

look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/202_xtend_classes_members.html#constructors)

Answer (score 2):

The next release of Xtend is planned for mid December. It'll have support for declaring constructors.

See http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/xtend/#whatsnext

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not yet supported in Xtend. The suggestion def Scope() is more a bug than a working constructor. You may want to follow this [ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363017).

Answer (score 1):

There is no constructor support in Xtend 2.0. I think it is a show stopper.

"class Foo { def Foo() { /*stuff*/ } } declares a method Foo on instances of Foo with the inferred return type, not a constructor, as browsing the generated Java code will show.

This implies that there is no way to extend Java classes that lack default constructors. XTend does not complain; it happily generates Java that does not compile.

Nor does XTend support immutable (final) instance variables, naturally enough.

Comment: Cheers dude. Definitely a show stopper. This has actually made me look at into scala.

Comment: This has changed in Xtend 2.1; there are other substantial improvements as well. Still no final variables.